How to configure "code runner" in VSCode to recognize custom modules?
I'm building a project that uses Python and C together, so instead of using Pycharm, I'm using VS Code as my main tool.
Here is my simple testing example to ensure everything is working correctly.
test.py
import sys
#import modules.custom

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.path)
    for path in sys.path:
        print(path)

And, my working directory is structured as follows:
-workspace
 |-modules
 | |-__init__.py
 | |-custom.py
 |-test
   |-test.py

I've set up the conda environment, configured the path to VSCode's python interpreter, added environment variables such as pythonpath, now F5 of VS Code itself is now working fine and the outputs are as follows
/mnt/e/workspace/test
/mnt/e/workspace/
XXXXXXX/lib/python3.9
......(other python paths)

However at the moment, "code runner" still can't find the custom module, cause the path printed via code runner doesn't contain the workspaceFolder. When running code with "code runner", the outputs are
/mnt/e/workspace/test
XXXXXXX/lib/python3.9
......(other python paths)

I feel really hard to learn how to use code runner :(. I've done some thing to fix the problem.

The code runner runs python in the "output" window by default, not in the "terminal", and the "output" window doesn't seem to display the print messages correctly. So I changed the configuration of code runner so that it always runs in the terminal. If this can cause any problem?

I've activated the conda environment in the terminal, so as shown above, the program started by code runner could find correct python interpreter and python packages. However, I still didn't find a way to get code runner to recognize the workspaceFolder directory, so custom modules still cannot be imported.



What makes you have to use Code Runner instead of the official extension Python?

@JialeDu Yeah it's not necessary indeed. I could also manage python and C code separately via Pycharm+VStudio, or just rely on the official VSCode plugins. But I still want to look for a simpler elegant way to deal with it. I previously thought that code runner could easily cope with multi-language scenario like this, but I'm actually running into these problems. I would like to know if there is something wrong with the way I am using it or the plugin itself. If you have any idea about how to handle this situation, hope you could share it with me!

Since the ability to select the interpreter or F5 debugging is provided by the official extension Python, it's normal that none of the settings you've made will work for CodeRunner. I searched and didn't find a place to set pythonpath in CodeRunner. What might work is to use sys.path.append() to add paths to the code.  https://imgur.com/LJIMyv6

Select Interpreter and debugging features, etc. have no effect on the Code Runner extension, as they are all settings and features brought by the official extension Python. And Code Runner simply and directly executes scripts using the python -u "path\to\name.py" command.
So you need to know which python environment your hcch is using first, I don't think it should be the conda environment you set up for vscde. You can use the following code to output the interpreter path.
import sys
print(sys.executable)


Once you know which python environment Code Runner is using, you can add the .pth file to the path\to\Python\Lib\site-packages and then add the workspace to it.


file structure：

